# uwsgi: os.getenv("PATH") does not work with /etc/environment in linux

Tags: python, linux, uwsgi

I am serving a Flask app with uwsgi and nginx.

I noticed that within the uwsgi threads os.getenv("PATH") outputs:

```
/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
```

Whereas my /etc/environment file is:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/opt/dcm4che-3.3.8/bin"
```

I have rebooted my system post changing /etc/environment so I do not see a reason as to why os.getenv("PATH") is not including the information from /etc/environment.

**Why is this happening?**

Comment: maybe you're running your app using `sudo` ?

Comment: The user who owns the uwsgi procs is www-data (just double checked it using top).

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: The uwsgi process is using a virtualenv - could that have something to do with it?

Comment: The `upstart` or `systemd` of your `linux` is probably not sourcing `/etc/environment`. Either source it from your script or move them to `/etc/profile.d` and `/etc/default`. And if you are running `sudo` within the script, you need to tell sudo to allow inheriting a PATH or set them within the script.

Comment: @alvits You were absolutely correct. Sourcing /etc/environment in /etc/default/uwsgi did the trick! Care to write an answer? I will gladly accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`upstart` or `systemd` isn't sourcing `/etc/environment`. You can move the environment variables to `/etc/default`.

By sourcing `/etc/environment` in `/etc/default/uwsgi` you practically moved the environment variables.